# How to convert json timezone object to java TimeZone using Gson?

Tags: java, gson

The server provides next response:

```
"timezone": {
    "gmtOffset": 7,
    "timeZoneId": "Asia/Novosibirsk",
    "dstOffset": 7
}
```

I use `Gson` to parse this `json`.
I tried to add field `private TimeZone timezone` to my DTO but `Gson` does not understand and throws the error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to invoke public java.util.TimeZone() with no args

Is there an easy way to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is someone`s custom fields set. Only custom deserializer may help.

```
public class TimeZoneDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<TimeZone> {

    @Override
    public TimeZone deserialize(
            JsonElement jsonElement,
            Type type,
            JsonDeserializationContext jsonDeserializationContext
    ) throws JsonParseException {
        String timezoneId = jsonElement
                .getAsJsonObject()
                .get("timeZoneId")
                .getAsString();

        return TimeZone.getTimeZone(timezoneId);
    }
}
```

Comment: Update: `TimeZone` became obsolete years ago, with the adoption of JSR 310. Now supplanted by [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneId.html).